# Roblox part appearing when clicked on another part

Tags: roblox

I need help, I have an idea for a game but one of the main mechanics does not work.  I need when you click a part another part appears

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? What is giving you difficulty? Please read the guide on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Answer (score 1):

> Roblox part appearing when clicked on another part

You can detect when a player clicks the part by putting a `ClickDetector` inside of it, then a `ServerScript` in that same part which will have a variable that points to the `ClickDetector`, using the `ClickDetector`'s `MouseClick` detect, you can use a `:Connect()` to create a new `Instance("Part")` in Workspace.

## Example

### Hierarchy

- Workspace
- - Terrain
- - Camera
- - Part
- - - Script
- - - ClickDetector

### Script

```
local clickdetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
clickdetector.MouseClick:Connect(function())
    ...
    local newPart = Instance.new("Part")
    newPart.Parent = workspace
    ...
end)
```

I hope this helped, you should research the [ClickDetector](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ClickDetector) and [Instance](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Instance) API references on the [ROBLOX DevHub](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/). Just keep in mind, if you don't give the new part a CFrame it will spawn at 0,0 in the world.

Comment: Although this is a detailed solution, I suggest reading the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code correctly.

Comment: @Tyler2P For some reason it didn't format it properly when I spoilered it despite having it  properly tabbed before.